# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem in aspx inline

Tags: asp.net

I have been asked to edit a .aspx script (i'm not aspx developer)

I need to put an if else statement from the column called PartnerStatus. If the value is True show as Active and if its false show as pending. Unfortunately i don't have access to the .dll file so i'm hoping i could add to the inline aspx script but i'm struggling. Below is snippet of the item template.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PartnerList" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td><asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" CssClass="blBtn" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartnerID") %>' OnClick="btn_Click"  Text="Edit" /></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Ref") %></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Contact") %></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Email") %></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Phone") %></td>
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartnerStatus") %></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator inline.

```
<td><%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("PartnerStatus")) == true ? "Active" : "Pending" %></td>
```

Note that this code assumes that `PartnerStatus` always has a value of True or False.

Or if you want to keep the same code

```
Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartnerStatus")) == true ? "Active" : "Pending"
```